# pygobject IconView interactive search

Tags: python, gtk3, pygobject

I'm using Python 3 with pygobject and I have an IconView and would like the user to be able to start typing and the IconView will select the first match. This already works in the TreeView widget, interactive search, but is there anyway to get this in an IconView. It works like this in pretty much every file explorer I've used on Linux but I can't figure out how it's done.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's only a skecth, but with some improvements can works as well: [IconView Search](https://gist.github.com/koMah/8159085)